# annoying auto file copy on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

While I'm developing an Android project, sometimes source files copying itself like `ActivityMain.java Activitymain(2).java`

It seems ActivityMain.java older version and `ActivityMain(2).java` current version.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Does it happen all of a sudden or when you do a certain action like saving the changes?

Comment: Where is your source code stored?  Are you using Dropbox or anything like that?

Comment: @Erol i couldn't catch the situation. When i try to run app i realize it has some error then i see that file has copyfile

Comment: @Simon you right, the project stored on yandex.disk